# Openerp Schdular execute at once

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I have created scheduled task and in local-host the scheduler with the function is working fine. In server I set Number of Calls=10, Interval Unit = Minutes and Interval Number = 1

The issue is when the server start after the particular upgrades , after only one minute the Number of Calls shows as 0 instead of 9

Please help me with this

The Function

```
def allocate_on_probations(self, cr, uid, ids,tl, context=None):

        allo=0
        state='active'
        result = {}


        emps=self.pool.get('hr.employee').search(cr, uid, [('current_status','=','active')], context=context)
        if emps:

            for r in emps:
                hol_state=2 
                gt_dt=cr.execute("""SELECT appointed_date FROM hr_employee WHERE id= %d order by id"""%(r))
                gt_dd=cr.fetchone()[0]

                #getting today details
                today = datetime.datetime.now()
                tt=today.date()
                td=tt.day
                tm=tt.month
                ty=tt.year

                #getting appointment date details
                app=datetime.datetime.strptime(gt_dd, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
                #print app
                ay=app.year
                am=app.month
                ad=app.day

                if ay==ty:
                    #compairing today and appointed date
                    comp=(tt-app)
                    chat=int(comp.days)
                    chat_mod=chat%30
                    print chat_mod
                    print r

                    if chat_mod==29:
                        hol_obj=self.pool.get('hr.holidays')
                        print hol_obj
                        condition_1=[('employee_id','=',r),('type','=','add'),('holiday_status_id','=',hol_state)]
                        hol_emp=hol_obj.search(cr, uid,condition_1, context=context)

                        if hol_emp:

                            for n in hol_emp:
                                hol_dt=cr.execute("""SELECT number_of_days_temp FROM hr_holidays WHERE id= %d order by id"""%(n))
                                hol_dd=cr.fetchone()[0]
                                hol_inc=(hol_dd+0.5)

                                print hol_inc
                                cr.execute("""UPDATE hr_holidays SET number_of_days_temp= %d WHERE id= %d"""%(hol_inc,n))
                                cr.execute("""UPDATE hr_holidays SET number_of_days= %d  WHERE id= %d"""%(hol_inc,n))




        return True
```

XML Scheduler call

```
<record id="ir_cron_scheduler" model="ir.cron">
            <field name="name">Casual Leave Allocation</field>
            <field name="interval_number">1</field>
            <field name="interval_type">minutes</field>
            <field name="numbercall">10</field>
            <field eval="False" name="doall"/>
            <field eval="'hr.holidays'" name="hr.holidays"/>
            <field eval="'allocate_on_probations'" name="allocate_on_probations"/>
            <field eval="'()'" name="args"/>
        </record>
```

UI
[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you do it via xml or from the ui?

Comment: initially I call the scheduler from xml and then just modified the arguments using ui

Comment: Then paste your code, for both the scheduler and the function you're running, it will be easier to debug that way

Comment: Added all UI, function and the xml call as you reqested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is with `Repeat missed`

When you set it to True, it means that missed actions that were missed when the server was down should be executed when the server restarts, so if the server was down for at least 10 minutes, when you restart it all the actions that were missed during that period would be executed as soon as possible. so don't untick that option, it's actually `False` in your code (Just upgrade your module to override the option in the UI)

you can also set the Argument that triggers the function from the xml

`<field eval="'(True,)'" name="args"/>`